# How to replace tabs with spaces?

Tags: indentation, tab-characters

Is it possible to convert tabs to spaces, while maintaining text alignment?

Simply replacing only works usefully when there are no leading characters.

Comment: If you have installed [vim-faq](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim_faq), you can get an offline answer there: `:h vim-faq` and search `/tab characters`. The hard to memorize tag is [`:h faq-14.16`](https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-14.16).

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You can use the `:retab` command. From 
[`:help :retab`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Aretab)

> Replace all sequences of white-space containing a `<Tab>` with new strings of
>   white-space using the new tabstop value given.  If you do not specify a new
>   tabstop size or it is zero, Vim uses the current value of `'tabstop'`.
>   [...]
>   With `'expandtab'` on, Vim replaces all tabs with the appropriate number of
>   spaces.

Note that the command accepts a range, so you can make a visual selection and
then just `:retab` the selected lines.

Comment: Cool! Works fast and simple!

Comment: how about providing an example?

Comment: `:ret` is 2 fewer keystrokes.  Does the same thing

Answer (score 30):

You can use `:retab`, as stated, however, this will change *all* tabs to spaces, *not* only tabs at the start of the line

So this (where `⇥` is a tab character):

```
if :; do
⇥echo "⇥hello"
end
```

gets changed to (where `␣` is a space character):

```
if :; do
␣␣echo "␣␣hello"
end
```

This can produce unexpected side-effects in some scenarios, and it's even more of an issue when changing spaces to tabs!

So, I wrote a little function to change *only* tabs/spaces at the *start* of the line:

```
" :retab changes *everything*, not just start of lines
fun! Retab(expandtab)
    let l:spaces = repeat(' ', &tabstop)

    " Replace tabs with spaces
    if a:expandtab
        silent! execute '%substitute#^\%(' . l:spaces . '\)\+#\=repeat("\t", len(submatch(0)) / &tabstop)#e'
    " Replace spaces with tabs
    else
        silent! execute '%substitute#^\%(\t\)\+#\=repeat("' . l:spaces . '", len(submatch(0)))#e'
    endif
endfun
```

With this version, you have to manually specify `expandtab` in the function call
(ie. `:call Retab(1)` to change tabs to spaces), but you could also modify it
to take the current value of `&expandtab` (as it already does with `&tabstop`)
just like `:retab` does. (I happen to prefer to specify it manually).

Comment: There is also [an answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5144480/500942) which covers retabbing at start of line only. It is worth linking because of the clarity of that explanation.

Comment: @JSV if you wish to suggest an edit to the author's code, I recommend leaving a comment about possible corrections or posting your own answer, especially when the new code is significantly different.

Answer (score 30):

Vim provides `:retab!` command which will replace all sequences of `<Tab>` with new strings of white-space using the new tabstop (e.g. `:set tabstop=2`) value given, but **all tabs inside of strings can be modified** (e.g. in a C program, you should use `\t` to avoid this)!

So alternatively you can change all tabs into spaces using the following command:

```
:%s/\t/  /g
```

or as suggested by [@Shahbaz](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/495/how-to-replace-tabs-with-spaces/844?noredirect=1#comment20357_844):

```
:%s/^\t\+/ /g
```

<sup>So only the tabs used in indentation are converted.</sup>

*Note*: there is a subtle difference between both commands. The first one will replace each Tab character by *two* spaces, the second one replace any number of leading Tab characters in a line by a *single* space.

Explanation:

- `%` represents the entire buffer/file (`:help :%`)
- `s` stands for substitute (`:help sub-replace-special`)
- `\t`, or `^I` stands for tab
- - use as many spaces as you need per one tab
- `g` - stands for global, and it'll convert multiple occurences of tabs in the same line

Then to correct indentation of the entire file, you may try: <kbd>gg=G</kbd>. Check: [Re-indenting badly indented code](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/236/467) for more details.

To use spaces by default instead of tabs, you need to add the following settings into your `.vimrc` file:

```
set tabstop=2     " (ts) width (in spaces) that a <tab> is displayed as
set expandtab     " (et) expand tabs to spaces (use :retab to redo entire file)
set shiftwidth=2  " (sw) width (in spaces) used in each step of autoindent (aswell as << and >>)
```

Alternative solution is to use `tidy`

---

Related:

- [Converting tabs to spaces](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces) at vim wikia
- [Indenting with spaces but still use preferred shiftwidth in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753219/indenting-with-spaces-but-still-use-preferred-shiftwidth-in-vim) at stackoverflow SE
- [How can I easily retab html files according to some sane default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20937/how-can-i-easily-retab-html-files-according-to-some-sane-default) at askubuntu SE
- [Is there a way to automatically un-tab everything in your source file by using a command?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110160/using-vim-is-there-a-way-to-automatically-un-tab-everything-in-your-source-file) at programmers
- [Re-indenting badly indented code](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/236/467) at Vim SE
- [Tab key == 4 spaces and auto-indent after curly braces in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234564/tab-key-4-spaces-and-auto-indent-after-curly-braces-in-vim) at stackoverflow
- [Indenting with spaces but still use preferred shiftwidth in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753219/indenting-with-spaces-but-still-use-preferred-shiftwidth-in-vim) at stackoverflow
- (opposite) [How can I convert spaces to tabs in Vim or Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104706/how-can-i-convert-spaces-to-tabs-in-vim-or-linux) at stackoverflow SE

Comment: I would at least do `%s/^\t\+/  g` so that only the tabs used in indentation are converted. Also, `gg=G` could be catastrophic with languages like python.

Comment: :%s/\t/  /g is the best solution and the easiest.

Comment: +1 for the `.vimrc` part

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
expand -t 4 input_filename output_filename
```

`expand` is a command-line tool to convert tabs to spaces, which you can run from a shell or with `:!expand`.

It's [in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expand.html) so it should be available on most systems. [`unexpand`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/unexpand.html) will do the reverse, by the way.

Comment: What is `expand`?

Comment: Expand is an inbuilt terminal command to copy tab character to spaces. Please find a detailed discription in the following link. http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uexpand.htm

Comment: If these are external commands, you should mention that.

Comment: Further description added. Please review

Comment: You could also just do `:%!expand -t 4` inside of vim.  Better yet, you could also use the current shift width option:  `:exe '%!expand -t ' . &shiftwidth`

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, `=` could also be used to fix indentations, after you have specified that tabs are replaced with spaces. In normal mode, you can do so by typing `:set expandtab`. Then `=` could be used in two ways:

- In Visual mode, a single `=` would fix indentations of selected code blocks.
- In normal mode, `gg=G` would fix the entire file, where `gg` moves the cursor to the beginning of the file, then `=` is applied, and `G` moves the cursor to the end of the file.

Reference: [link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_indentation)

Comment: This assumes vim can recompute the current indentation correctly *(may not be the case)* - also for unstructured files, or code written in a different editor with slightly different indentation rules.

Comment: Thanks @ideasman42; I've added to the answer to be more complete.