# Substitute all tabs with four blank spaces

Tags: autocmd

The following command will substitute all tabs in a file with four blank spaces:

```
%s/\t/    /g
```

In order to run this command whenever I open a new file I included it in my .vimrc by adding:

```
autocmd BufNewFile  *   exec "%s/\t/    /g"
```

However this didn't work.  Does anyone know why?

Comment: New files don't contain any tabs, because they are empty. Are you looking for `BufRead`?

Comment: Also, you might be interested in the `:retab` command.

Comment: This is a very dangerous command. It will alter every file you open automatically. And if the file is `readonly` or `nomodifiable` it will probably throw a bunch of errors, also the use of `gdefault` has to be considered. I would not recommend this setting! Better would be to set your `tabstop` setting appropriately and have Vim display tabs as 4 spaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace tabs with spaces?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/495/how-to-replace-tabs-with-spaces)

Answer (score 1):

```
autocmd BufRead  *   exec "%s/\t/    /g"
```

Comment: you don't need the `exe`. BTW: are you sure you want to alter existing files automatically?

Comment: I am sure i want to alter existing files automatically.